# c3 chart in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, c3.js

I have my JSON data from URL using angular js and assigned to `$scope.values`. Now I want to feed this value to chart using the c3 chart.

I have a dummy chart using below code.

```
jsonData.forEach(function(e) {
    sites.push(e.name);
    })    
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart1',
    data: {
        json: [ data ],
```

How can I pass the json values to the chart?

Answer (score 0):

The `data.json` is expecting following format:

```
data: {
  json: {
    data1: [1,3,3,7],
    otherdata: [9,0,0,0]
  }
}
```

You can either pass multiple columns to `data.json` or you can add each colmn kinda manually.

```
var myjson = { data1:[1,3,3,7], data2:[9,0,0,0] }

data: {
      json: myjson
} 

var mydata = [1,3,3,7]

data: {
  json: {
    data1: mydata
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually from the http url I am getting result in json format, that response I am setting to $scope.values.In the same controller, I want to feed this value to c3 chart.But I am not getting the data

Comment: What do you mean with "not getting the data"? How does your json look like? When your json does not have the same structure like I explained, it won't create any datapoints for the chart.

Comment: After setting the timeout function, I am able to get the data. In y chart I am trying to change the color of bars but when I use color: {} it is showing error in eclipse for the attribute color. I wanted to change the color of of bar based on some condition for eg.status Up green colordown-red color.Can anyone give idea for this